# two way binding attribute directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need two way data binding in an attribute for the progressBar directive provided by bootstrap.

Inside the progressBar component we have the following

```
.constant('uibProgressConfig', {
  animate: true,
  max: 100
})
```

When I use this in my html I have this.

```
<uib-progress ng-repeat="bar in myCtrl.stacked track by $index" animate="myCtrl.isRunning" value="{{bar.value}}" type="{{bar.type}}"
      style="width:{{myCtrl.percentage}}%; border-right: 1px solid #000; border-radius: 0px">
```

What I want is that animate value attribute with two way databinding.

```
animate="myCtrl.isRunning"
```

The problem is that I can't use

```
animate={{myCtrl.isRunning}}
```

because I get the error

> Error: $parse:syntax Syntax Error Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{field}}.$error] starting at [{field}}.$error].

Is there anyway to bind this attribute "animate" to a model?

Comment: to do two way data binding, you need you use ng-model, can you provide your JS code?

Comment: I can't use ng-model for the attribute animate in the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the animate attribute is read only once when the directive controller is initialized.  It is neither `$watched` nor `$observed`

From ui-bootstrap.js::UibProgressController

```
animate = angular.isDefined($attrs.animate) ? $scope.$parent.$eval($attrs.animate) : progressConfig.animate;
```

You may need to fork the module and add an `$attrs.$observe('animate', setAnimate)` in the `UibProgressController`

Comment: Yeah I saw that yesterday. Finally is what I finished doing. Modifying the core code to add a watcher into that attribute that is defined as a constant. I mark as resolved because basically this is what I did to solve my problem.